# (Discord.js) Trying to get a channel id based on the name of the channel, and post a message in it

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to set up a server with a bunch of text channels named after users so that I can read their DMs to the bot. I can't figure out how to find if a text channel with that person's tag exists already, and I'm not sure if this is the correct code to do this.
Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
try{
        var txtChannel = client.guilds.cache.get(dmServerID).channels.find(channel => channel.name === (mesage.author.tag.replace('#','-')) && channel.type === "text");
    }
    catch(e){
        client.guilds.cache.get(dmServerID).channels.create(message.author.tag.replace('#', '-'), 'text');
    }
    txtChannel.send(message.author.tag + ": " + message.content);
```

After running this code, it gives me an error that reads: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.
I would also like to know if I am able to create the text channels inside of a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `let` over `var`.
The error is caused by the fact that you declare txtChannel inside the `try` so it is not available outside that block of code.
Also, you forgot `channels.cache` (if you are using discord.js v12).

Here is what the code should look like:

```js
let txtChannel = null;
// Already get the guild from the cache since we are gonna use it a bit
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);

// Find a text channel that includes in the name the tag of the user
txtChannel = GUILD.channels.cache.find(c => c.type === "text" && c.name.includes(message.author.tag.replace('#','-'));

// If the channel doesn't exist we create the channel, using await to wait until the channel gets successfully created
if(!txtChannel) txtChannel = await GUILD.channels.create(message.author.tag);

// At the end we send the message in the gotten / created channel
txtChannels.send("the message to send");
```

Note that this code needs to be inside an async function, you can read more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: While this does create the channel and post a message in it, it always creates a new channel, even if one already exists. So if I DM the bot multiple times, it creates a new channel for each message.

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to make the author's tag lowercase. Thanks.